# Tampermonkey, with Greasy Fork "Return Pagination to Google '' script - "No script runnng" error

Tags: tampermonkey

I have installed the Tampermonkey script manager extension into my Google Chrome web browser from the Chrome Web Store, and installed the "Return Pagination to Google '' script, from Greasy Fork, into that extension.

The problem that I’m having, however, is that the Tampermonkey icon at the top of the browser page displays a “No script running” entry, just beneath a checked off, “enabled” entry - which appears directly above such - while the function that the script is supposed to be performing (i.e., of returning pagination to the bottom of google search results pages), does not appear to be either present &/or enabled / operating, at all. Moreover, the Tampermonkey dashboard also further reflects the script as being both present and installed, and enabled, as well.

This is totally confusing to me as I am completely new to all if this and understand nothing at all about scripts or “scripting” or computer code / language etc., as it’s all completely Greek to me, and like trying to decipher a world of hieroglyphics, with zero knowledge or comprehension &/or understanding, of even where to begin, etc.,  . . . ‘though I am trying.

So, what I have tried this far – and multiple times - is as follows:

1. I have checked to make sure Tampermonkey is enabled
2. I have Verified script is installed (and no other script has been installed, as this is the first)
3. I have Reinstalled Tampermonkey
4. I have Reinstalled the script
5. I have Cleared all browser caches and cookies (with “Ccleaner” desktop app / utility)
6. I have tried executing, with all other extensions disabled
7. I have ran / checked for Windows updates, for my Windows 10 operating platform on the HP  notebook PC, which I an running.
8. I have done a complete system check, to make sure all programs and apps are up to date
9. I have executed “%temp%, “temp” and “prefetch” select all and delete RUN commands, with “disk cleanup,” via control panel
10. I have executed “sfc /scannow” command in command prompt, at administrate level, to check system files / integrity, and all is well

Aside from all of that, I don’t know what else to do.

As well, however, and on another note, I have noticed that when clicking on the “Return Pagination to Google '' script entry from within the Tampermonkey dashboard, which brings up the installed / relevant script, in a scrollable panel, that “multiple” icon-type red circles with white exes inside of them, and at least one yellow triangle, with a black exclamation mark inside of it, appear within the left margin portion of the numbered, line-by-line entries, of correspondent / relative script.

Respectively, these appear, as follows:

1. Line 6 text reads / shows, as:  // Thank you, Yappa and kenuKi.
   Red circle beside such presents popup that says:  eslint: userscripts/no-invalid-metadata –      Attributes – should begin with @
2. Line 11 text reads / shows, as:  // @description 10/13/2023, 2:45 AM
   Yellow triangle beside such presents popup that says:  eslint: userscripts/require-description – Include only one description for each language
3. Line 159 text reads / shows, as:  var botstuffDiv = document.getElementById('botstuff');
   Red circle beside such presents popup that says:  eslint: no-redeclare – ‘botstuffDiv’ is already defined.
4. Line 161 text reads / shows, as:  for (var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++) {
   Red circle beside such presents popup that says:  eslint: no-redeclare – ‘1’ is already defined.
5. Line 225 text reads / shows, as:  for (var i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
   Red circle beside such presents popup that says:  eslint: no-redeclare – ‘1’ is already defined.
6. Line 226 text reads / shows, as:  var column = table.querySelector(`.ret-pag-col-${i}`);
   Red circle beside such presents popup that says:  no-redeclare – ‘column’ is already defined
7. Line 235 text reads / shows, as:  for (var i = 9; i >= 2; i--) {
   Red circle beside such presents popup that says:  no-redeclare – ‘1’ is already defined.
8. Line 236 text reads / shows, as:  var column = table.querySelector(`.ret-pag-col-${i}`);
   Red circle beside such presents popup that says:  no-redeclare – ‘column’ is already defined
9. Line 237 text reads / shows, as:  var columnNumber = pageNumber - (10 - i);
   Red circle beside such presents popup that says:  no-redeclare – ‘columnNumber’ is already defined

So, can anyone help me, please, in very simple and plain English; non-technical, step-by-step language, for beginners, how do I fix this "No script is running," issue, in Tampermonkey script manager extension, for google chrome?

Please note that I would be glad to attach a copy here of how the scrolling / script window appears w/in the dashboard on my pc / Tampermonkey display, for you, so that you could see it first-hand, and as a  better point of reference, for yourself, but I don’t know how to do that – and I’m not sure, if I did, if it would fit within whatever might be required, as related file size limitations etc., or how such could be “made to fit” w/In those specifications, if such a file size were to be too large.

Alternatively, if unable to resolve this on my own via whatever assistance may be offered here, does anyone know of any remote tech support assistance services via which I could grant remote access to my PC, for them to handle / work on and resolve this for me – w/out having to pay an arm and a leg or be subjected to some type of ridiculous price gouging? (Being disabled / low income on my end, makes this all the more challenging).

Thank you for your tremendous patience and for whatever guidance &/or  assistance you may be able to provide in these resects, in advance.

Sincerely,
SteveM

Comment: FOLLOW-UP for antone else this nay helo.  Resolurion found here: https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/468360-return-pagination-to-google/discussions/210203